# wsdl.exe results in "SOAP 1.1 binding was not found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to implement an HTML Parsing web service as described in Chapter 23 of *ASP.NET Unleashed* (1st ed.) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxb0bsdh.aspx).  So far, so good!  However, I do get an annoying warning when using wsdl.exe to generate the class:

```
Microsoft (R) Web Services Description Language Utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3038]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Warning: This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.
SOAP 1.1 binding was not found: WS-I's Basic Profile 1.1 consists of 
implementation guidelines that recommend how a set of core Web services
specifications should be used together to develop interoperable Web 
services. For the 1.1 Profile, those specifications are SOAP 1.1, 
WSDL 1.1, UDDI 2.0, XML 1.0 and XML Schema.

For more details on the WS-I Basic Profile v1.1, see the specification
at http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html.
```

I'd like to conform to the specification if possible.  I looked at the [recommended page](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html) and found a couple pages on w3.org, but didn't find a concrete example of what xml elements I need to include in order to conform.

In lieu of posting my xml, I'll just say the wsdl roughly conforms to what is used in the MSDN article (except I fixed the invalid URL for the XMLSchema on w3.org by adding ".dtd").

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Wsdl.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx) use by default **SOAP** as the protocol to implement and in consequence tries to check the conformance to the Basic Profile. Anyway, `wsdl.exe` handles this and continues with only a warning. If you check the [MSDN article file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxb0bsdh.aspx), you will note that the binding is configure to use **HttpGet** protocol. So, if you want to suppress the warning, run

```
wsdl.exe /protocol:HttpGet <url or path>
```

However, the resulting proxy class is the same with the previous one.

*Side note*: You don't have to fix any URL that defines a namespace, since it is not used as URL but as identifier. Although many namespaces look like URLs, they need not point to actual resources on the Web. The namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` is defined by W3C in [XML Schema recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/).